# Activity Indicator is not showing on images

Tags: ios, iphone, activity-indicator

Hi I'm trying to upload image's from iphone to server in that i given activity indicator for the user to known that image is uploading while clicking upload it will show activity indicator for few minutes.

But my problem is the activity indicator only showing in few images its not showup on all the images pls tell me how to resolve this.

my activity coding .

```
-(void)temp{
    spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    //spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:]
     spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0);
    [spinner setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 240)]; // (mid of screen) I do this because I'm in landscape mode
    [self.view addSubview:spinner];
    spinner.color = [UIColor blackColor];
    spinner.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2 alpha:0.4];
    [spinner startAnimating];
    [spinner release];
}

-(void) myMethod{
    [spinner stopAnimating];
    spinner.hidden = YES;
    spinner.color = [UIColor yellowColor];
}

- (IBAction)pushUpload:(id)sender {

    [self temp];
    [self performSelector:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0f];

}
```

Comment: have you added indicator on imageview or below imageview????

Comment: One thing is pretty clear with the provided limited info. You are trying to reuse a single activity indicator for multiple images.

Comment: @NiravPatel above imageview its showing only in the few images but its not showing ot all the images pls tell how to resolve it..

Comment: @Desdenova evertime when they press the activity indicator should display pls tell me how to resolve this

Comment: try to replace this line "spinner.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2 alpha:0.4];" with spinner.backgroundColor = [UIColor bluecolor]; . please check whether background color is changing to bluecolor or not...

Comment: @NiravPatel i have already tried that its not working on that also ..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ActivityIndicator use AsynchronousImageView It will automatically add activityindicator while loading an image.

**[AsynObj loadImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageUrl]];**

You can get the AsyncImageView classes from the following link  https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView

I hope it will help!